# react: правильный подход к формированию компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

подскажите как правильно реализовать следующий функционал:

- есть массив строк, описывающих тэги (передается компоненту)
- если тегов больше 10, то отрисовываются первые 10 тегов и кнопка сворачивания/разворачивания тэгов
- если кнопка разворачивания тэгов нажата, то отрисовываются все тэги

Реализую компонент (для демонстрации выкинул некоторые свойства `Button` и `Badge` чтоб не захламлять тут код)

```
class BlockTags extends React.Component<IProps_BlockTags, IState_BlockTags> {
    // конструктор
    constructor(
        props: IProps_BlockTags
    ) {
        super(props);

        // задать состояние компонента
        this.state = {
            is_collapsed:   false,
            content:        this.props.content
        };
    }

    // callback: нажата кнопка сворачивания/разворачивания
    handleCollapse = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        this.setState({
            is_collapsed: !this.state.is_collapsed
        });
    }

    // отрисовать компонент
    render() {
        if (this.state.content === undefined)
            return <></>

        // сформировать актуальный список тэгов
        const tags: string[] = Array.from(new Set(this.state.content.map((tag: string) => tag.toLowerCase())));
        const compacted_tags: string[] = this.state.is_collapsed ? tags : tags.slice(0, 10);

        // отрисовать тэги
        return <div className = 'tags-panel'>
            {compacted_tags.map((tag: string, index: number) => <Badge text = {tag} key = {`tag_${index}`} />)}
            {tags.length >= 10 &&
                <Button
                    onClick = {this.handleCollapse}
                    icon = {this.state.is_collapsed ? <IconUp /> : <IconDown />}
                />
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

И вот у меня, как у новичка в этом деле, возникло несколько вопросов:

1. подготовку тэгов стоит перенести в `handleCollapse` и конструктор, убрав из `render`?
2. стоит ли дублировать свойство из `props` в `state`, если оно никак не меняется, а используется как есть?

Вообще что по таким задачам говорит реакторная наука? :)
Что ещё плохого у меня в коде, что лучше изменить и никогда больше нигде не повторять?

Comment: Я конечно больше в react-native, но мне кажется, что для обычного реакта тоже рекомендация уходить от классовых компонентов, в пользу функциональных. Или это существующий проект?

Comment: рабочий проект
на счет классовых и функциональных слышал, но так и не понял - ПОЧЕМУ? как по мне классовые как-то более удобные, понятные и логичные, особенно, когда компонент более-менее крупный (строчек 100-150)